# Tomcat 7 выбрасывает отчет сделанный на TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: tomcat

Есть проект java технология spring, как только увеличился отчет(т.е. работает больше 30-40пользователей) стало через 2-3часа выходить ошибка, точнее выкидывает. Отчет сделан на TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio-6.6.0. После перезагрузки сервера отчет снова работает 2-3 часа. Ошибку выложу позже. Сервер на Tomcat 7.

Comment: увеличился отчет(т.е. работает больше 30-40пользователей) - отчет стал более полновестным, запросы в отчете из oracle sql, пользователи 30-40человек

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for: pg_form_1_1.
type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for: pg_form_1_1.

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.